# What do you get when you add $i$ to the totally real numbers?

Tags: extension-field

Say that an algebraic number $\alpha\in{\mathbb C}$ is totally real
iff ${\mathbb Q}[\alpha]$ is a [totally real number field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_real_number_field). The totally 
real numbers obviously form a subfield of $\mathbb R$, which I will denote
by $\mathbb T$.

I ask myself several questions on the field ${\mathbb F}={\mathbb T}[i]$ :
  is it equal to ${\mathbb C}$ ? What is the intersection 
  ${\mathbb F}\cap {\mathbb R}$ ?

The [famous theorem of Artin&Schreier](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) is obviously related to this, but I'm not sure how it might help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${\bf F}\cap{\bf R}={\bf T}$$ because $${\bf F}=\{\,a+bi:a,b\in{\bf T}\,\}$$ Since ${\bf T}\subset{\bf R}$, an element $a+bi$ of $\bf F$ is in $\bf R$ if and only if $b=0$, so said element of $\bf F$ is already in $\bf T$.

Answer (score 3):

You can't hope for it to equal $\mathbb{C}$: the most you could possibly hope for is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

However, you don't get that: the algebraic closure of a field is a finite-degree extension if and only if the field itself is either real closed or is already algebraically closed.

Every real closed field is ordered and every positive number has a square root. $\mathbb{T}$ cannot be real closed: if $\alpha$ is any nonzero element that is neither totally positive nor totally negative, then neither $\sqrt{\alpha}$ nor $\sqrt{-\alpha}$ are totally real, and thus neither is an element of $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: Good, though I don't think it completely answers the question. Does adjoining $i$ give you any real numbers you didn't have before?

Comment: For example, does $\sqrt[3]{2}\in {\mathbb T}[i]$ ? I guess the answer is no, but I see no easy way to show it.

Comment: $[\mathbb{T}(\sqrt[3]{2}) : \mathbb{T}] = 3$, but $[\mathbb{T}(i) : \mathbb{T}] = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to showing $\mathbb T(i) \cap \mathbb R = \mathbb T$: we have
$$
\mathbb T \subset \mathbb T(i) \cap \mathbb R \subset \mathbb T(i)
$$
and the second containment is strict since $i \in \mathbb T(i)$ and $i \not\in \mathbb T(i) \cap \mathbb R$. Since $[\mathbb T(i):\mathbb T] = 2$, the middle field must be the bottom field: $\mathbb T(i) \cap \mathbb R = \mathbb T$.